# Cannot attach FileLogger when running MSBuild 4.0 programmatically

Tags: c#, msbuild, msbuild-4.0

I'm trying to get the logs when running MSBuild 4.0 in my C# code.

var fileLogger = new Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.FileLogger() { Parameters = @"C:\MSBuild.log") };

```
var projectCollection = new ProjectCollection();
var buildParamters = new BuildParameters(projectCollection);
buildParamters.Loggers = new List<Microsoft.Build.Framework.ILogger>() { new Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.FileLogger() { Parameters = @"C:\MSBuild.log" }};

var globalProperty = new Dictionary<String, String>();
globalProperty.Add("Configuration", "Debug");
globalProperty.Add("Platform", "Any CPU");

BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.ResetCaches();

var buildRequest = new BuildRequestData(projectFile, globalProperty, null, new String[] { "Clean", "Build" }, null);
var buildResult = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(buildParamters, buildRequest);
```

However, after the build is completed (either succeeded or failed), no log file was generated. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the Parameters passed to FileLogger, it should be like this, note the `logfile=` :

```
Parameters = @"logfile=c:\MSBuild.log"
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.buildengine.consolelogger.parameters%28v=vs.121%29.aspx

Comment: Haven't got a chance to test it, but hopefully this is it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to **stijn's** answer:

Here are all available parameters:

> **LogFile**=C:\LogPath\LogFile.log;**Append**;**NoAutoFlush**;**Encoding**=UTF-8;

Defaults (if a parameter is not specified):

> LogFile: **msbuild.log** (will be created in the current directory, e.g
>   Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
>
> Append: **false** (no append)
>
> NoAutoFlush: **false** (auto flush is on)
>
> Encoding: **System.Text.Encoding.Default**